# BroadcastReceiver stopped after a while

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have defined a **BroadcastReceiver** in app **manifset**.
I used it for doing some job on predefined intervals.
After a while ( maybe a couple of months) the **BroadcastReceiver** stops receiving broadcasts.
Rerunning app doesn't solve problem.
The point is clearing data or cache doesn't solve problem.
Uninstalling and reinstalling even has no effect.
The only solution is to uninstall, then reboot, then reinstall!

Answer (score 0):

It later versions, BroadcastReceiver will not receive broadcast after you force close it.